# Analyzing the color composition of a video

Tags: python, image, child-process, video

Here is a snippet of code from a project I have been working on that can be found [here](https://github.com/nafarius333/VideoColorAnalyzer/tree/d2bb1236b6d49946a6ffa1f53d03cea6579ef7cd).  I am looking for suggestions on how I can improve my code to make it cleaner and maybe improve performance.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import subprocess as sp
import numpy
from pathlib import Path
import argparse
import AverageColor

def usage():
    print("USAGE: videoparser.py --file {FILENAME} -f --FRAME {NUMBER OF FRAMES TO SKIP")


def get_resolution(path):
    out = sp.check_output(["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-of", "flat=s=_",
        "-select_streams", "v:0", "-show_entries", "stream=height,width", path])

    lines = out.split("\n")
    vidwidth = lines[0].split('=')[1]
    vidheight = lines[1].split('=')[1]
    return vidwidth, vidheight

# Get the arguments from the command line and assign them to variables
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Analyze the change in colors of videos over time")
parser.add_argument('-f', "--frames", dest="FRAMESKIPCOUNT", default=24)
parser.add_argument('--file', dest="FILENAME", required=True)
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

FRAME_SKIP_COUNT = args['FRAMESKIPCOUNT']
FILENAME = args['FILENAME']
if args['FRAMESKIPCOUNT']:
    FRAME_SKIP_COUNT = int(args['FRAMESKIPCOUNT'])

# Make sure the file is valid
my_file = Path(FILENAME)
if not my_file.is_file():
    raise FileNotFoundError('File was not found', args['FILENAME'])

# Run the command to start the FFMPEG library
FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg.exe"

command = [FFMPEG_BIN,
           '-i', FILENAME,
           '-f', 'image2pipe',
           '-pix_fmt', 'rgb24',
   '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-']

pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=10 ** 8, shell=True)  # Open pipe to start receiving pixel data
i = 0  # i is for processing every 'FRAME_SKIP_COUNT'th element
pos = 0  # to hold the position to draw the next line
width, height = get_resolution(FILENAME)
# Declare a blank image and prepare it for drawing
finalImage = Image.new("RGB", (20000, height))
finalImageDraw = ImageDraw.Draw(finalImage, "RGB")

while True:
    # read 1 frame
    raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(1280*720*3)

    if i % FRAME_SKIP_COUNT == 0:
        # transform the byte read into a numpy array
        image = numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
        if image.size == 0:
            # No more data, reached the end of the video
            break
        # Put the data into an image for processing (Can this be skipped to improve performance?)
        image = image.reshape((720, 1280, 3))
        img = Image.fromarray(image, 'RGB')

        avgColor = AverageColor.averagecolorfromimage(img)
        # Draw a line
        finalImageDraw.line([(pos, 0), (pos, height)], fill="rgb" + str(avgColor))
        pos += 1
    # throw away the data in the pipe's buffer.
    pipe.stdout.flush()
    i += 1
# Crop the image and save it
finalImage = finalImage.crop([0, 0, pos, 1000])
finalImage.save(FILENAME + " - color.png")
```

Here is the AverageColor implementation

```
from pathlib import Path

from PIL import Image


def averagecolorfromfile(file):

    file = Path(file)
    if not file.is_file():
        raise FileNotFoundError('File was not found', file)

    im = Image.open(file)

    # create list of pixel's RGB values and their count (stored in color[0])
    colors = im.getcolors(1000000)

    im.close()

    count = 0
    c1 = 0
    c2 = 0
    c3 = 0

    # add all the values up and divide by the total number of
    # pixels to get the average rgb value

    for color in colors:
        count += color[0]
        c1 += (color[1][0] * color[0])
        c2 += (color[1][1] * color[0])
        c3 += (color[1][2] * color[0])

    c1 /= count
    c2 /= count
    c3 /= count

    return int(c1), int(c2), int(c3)


def averagecolorfromimage(image):

    # create list of pixel's RGB values and their count (stored in color[0])
    colors = image.getcolors(1000000)

    count = 0
    c1 = 0
    c2 = 0
    c3 = 0

    # add all the values up and divide by the total number of
    # pixels to get the average rgb value

    for color in colors:
        count += color[0]
        c1 += (color[1][0] * color[0])
        c2 += (color[1][1] * color[0])
        c3 += (color[1][2] * color[0])

    c1 /= count
    c2 /= count
    c3 /= count

    return int(c1), int(c2), int(c3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative implementation of `averagecolorfromfile`:

```
import scipy.ndimage

def averagecolorfromfile2(file):
    "Return mean color of the pixels in the image loaded from file."
    return scipy.ndimage.imread(file).mean(axis=(0, 1)).round().astype('uint8')
```

I find that this is about 16 times as fast as the code in the post:

```
>>> data = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(1000, 1000, 3), dtype='uint8')
>>> filename = 'cr153189.png'
>>> PIL.Image.fromarray(data).save(filename)
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit(lambda:averagecolorfromfile(filename), number=1)
1.599527531012427
>>> timeit(lambda:averagecolorfromfile2(filename), number=1)
0.09920550498645753
```

Note also that `averagecolorfromfile` returns a *truncated* result (that is, rounded towards zero). But for most purposes it would be more accurate to round to the nearest integer, as in `averagecolorfromfile2`:

```
>>> averagecolorfromfile(filename)
(127, 127, 127)
>>> averagecolorfromfile2(filename)
array([127, 128, 128], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what scipy.ndimage.imread(file) is doing, or point me to some material to read. I am trying to wrap my head around it but I don't quite understand why it works.

Comment: @JacobMalachowski: See the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html#scipy.ndimage.imread).